# Como salvar uma imagem de um formulário para o banco

Tags: php, html, imagem, formulário

No meu formulário, o usuário coloca as informações do seu pedido e uma imagem para referência, porém, essa imagem não está sendo salva junto com o registro.

**O formulário:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="utf-8">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Documento</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_FILES)){
            $dir = "../img/";
            $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $dir.$image)){

                $image = $_FILES['image'];

                $strcon = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','', 'db_formacao') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
                $sql = "INSERT INTO imagens SET image = '$image'" 
                mysqli_query($strcon,$sql) or die("Erro ao tentar cadastrar registro");
                mysqli_close($strcon);

                echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Salvo com Sucesso !");
                        window.history.go(-1);
                    </script>';
                ?>
            }
        }
    ?>
    <form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
        Selecione uma imagem:
        <input name="image" type="file"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Tá dando o erro 500, a página não está funcionando.

É a primeira vez que eu tento salvar uma imagem, então, se algo tiver absurdamente errado, me aponte. :)

Comment: Como está o `tipo` do campo no seu banco de dados ?

Comment: Então, está varchar mesmo. Procurei uma opção mais adequada mas não achei,

Comment: O correto seria "blob" . Dê uma olhada aqui: http://www.devmedia.com.br/armazenando-imagens-no-mysql/32104

Comment: @RaoniBZ O correto seria `blob`? tem certeza?

Comment: Sua linha do `SQL` está errada, altere para isso `$sql = "INSERT INTO imagens SET campo ='$image'` e para pegar o nome da imagem, você precisa fazer assim `$image = $_FILES['imagem']['name']`

Comment: @RafaelAugusto até onde sei, sim, o blob ! Qual seria ?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto `INSERT INTO imagens SET campo ='$image'` ???

Comment: @RaoniBZ A melhor pratica é armazenar apenas o nome do arquivo no banco e a imagem no diretorio do servidor.

Comment: @RaoniBZ Qual sua duvida referente a minha resposta no comentario a cima?

Comment: @RafaelAugusto com certeza ! Tenho até exemplo pronto disso, mas a pergunta não foi essa.

Comment: Porque não o values, se é o mais comum ? `INSERT INTO imagens (imagem) VALUES ('$image')`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67575/discussion-between-raoni-bz-and-rafael-augusto).

Comment: Não se trata de ser comum ou não, não tem `sintaxe` errada, uma é do `SQL` e outra do `Mysql`, eu dei um exemplo da forma que eu uso, o que não impede ela de usar com `values`, e ainda descobrir que é possivel com `SET`

Answer (score 1):

Para manipular um arquivo, deve-se usar o

$_FILES (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.files.php)

Salvar imagens no banco não é uma boa prática nem de longe ! rs

Como pediu pelo chat, um exemplo completo do envio do arquivo para um diretório e os dados do arquivo no banco:
(pegue uma imagem com nome de "loading.gif" e deixe na pasta raiz, assim irá exibir ela enquanto o form envia)

*** Crie uma pasta "anexos" na pasta raiz.

index.php

```
<html>
<head>  
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#formulario").submit(function() {
                $('#formulario').hide();
                $('.imagens').hide();
                $('#gif').show();
                //return true;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="loading.gif" id="gif" height="auto" width="200" hidden>

    <form id="formulario" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="_envio.php">
        Selecione uma imagem: 
        <input name="arquivoX" type="file"/>
        <br/>
        <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
    </form>

    <?
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    $srv    = "enderecoDoBanco";
    $user   = "usuarioDoBanco";
    $pass   = "senhaDoBanco";
    $db     = "nomeDoBanco";

    $db = new mysqli($srv, $user, $pass, $db);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM anexos";
    $res = $db -> query($sql);

    while ($i = $res -> fetch_assoc()) {

        $a[] = $i;

        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($i);
        //echo $i['dir'].$i['arq'];
        ?>
        <img class="imagens" src="<?echo 'anexos\\'.$i['arq']?>" height="60" width="60"/>
        <?
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

_envia.php

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$srv    = "enderecoDoBanco";
$user   = "usuarioDoBanco";
$pass   = "senhaDoBanco";
$db     = "nomeDoBanco";

$db = new mysqli($srv, $user, $pass, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<div style="background-color:green;color:white"><b>OK :: CONEXAO BD</b></div><hr>';
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

$uploaddir = 'F:\Xampp\htdocs\_commands\files\anexos\\';
$uploadfile = time() . '-' . basename($_FILES['arquivoX']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivoX']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir.$uploadfile)) {

    // Gera endereço da pasta para o mysql
    $dir = str_replace('\\', '\\\\', $uploaddir);

    // ******* TRATAR NOME (acentos, etc)

    $arq = $uploadfile;
    $extpat = pathinfo($_FILES['arquivoX']['name']);
    $ext = $extpat['extension'];

    echo '<div style="background-color:green;color:white">OK :: Arquivo válido e enviado com sucesso.<br></div>';
    $db -> query("INSERT INTO anexos (`dir`,`arq`,`ext`) VALUES ('$dir','$arq','$ext')");

} else {

    echo '<div style="background-color:orange;color:white">WARNING :: Possível ataque de upload de arquivo!<br></div>';
}

if ($db -> close()) {
    echo '<div style="background-color:blue;color:white"><b>OK :: CONEXAO BD CLOSE</b></div><hr>';
} else {
    echo '<div style="background-color:orange;color:white"><b>WARNING :: CONEXAO DB CLOSE</b></div><hr>';
}

sleep(3);

header('Location: index.php');

?>
```

Comment: Esse uploaddir em _envia.php é equivalente ao meu endereço da pasta imagens, certo?

Comment: Que "arquivoX" é esse? Que "extension" é esse?

Comment: sim ! o uploaddir é o diretório que será enviada a imagem (tome cuidado, pegue uma imagem pequena para teste, pois o php limita tamanho)

Comment: O nome "arquivoX" é o do input no index  `<input name="arquivoX" type="file"/>`

Comment: E esse "extension" é para extrair a extensão do arquivo. Assim eu sei o tipo de cada. Mas isso foi um TESTE para testar essas variáveis todas.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações e tá dando erro 404. Vou atualizar a pergunta.

Comment: Você está simulando isso onde ? Seu cenário aceita "short tag" =  `<?` ao invés de `<?php`